# Check if there is a given string in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to **check** if there is a **particular** string in the dictionary **value's** and I have tried in this way, but it isn't working.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();


dict["John"] = new List<string>() { "pop", "folk" };
dict["Mark"] = new List<string>() { "pop-folk", "jazz" };

if (dict.ContainsValue(new List<string>() { "pop" }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no");
}
```

I want to check if there is the string **"pop"** and I expect **"yes"** but the code isn't working. Another example is to check if there is **"dance"** and the expected output will be **"no"**. I hope you understand what I mean. I will be very grateful if you can explain to me the best way to do that.

Comment: first idea - in foreach loop check if `value` as `List` contains your element (`pop` or `dance`).  Your `dict.ContainsValue(new List<string>() { "pop" })` isn't working cause in `dict` there are no such value as `new List<string>() { "pop" }`. In `dict` you have values that contains partially your value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dict.ContainsValue` won't work for two reasons:

- `List<T>` doesn't override `Equals`, so you're checking for reference equality against a new object
- `ContainsValue` looks for for an *equal* value - you want to look for a value that contains a particular key. It would be an odd equality comparer that claimed that a list with two different values is equal to one of those values.

Fortunately the solution is simple. You can use `dictionary.Values` to get a sequence of values, then use `Any` to check whether *any* of the values contains the one you're looking for:

```
private static bool ContainsValue(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string value)
    => dictionary.Values.Any(list => list.Contains(value));
```

As noted elsewhere, if you regularly find yourself using the dictionary like this, that's probably an indication that you should use a different data structure. It will definitely work, but doesn't take advantage of the cheap "look up by key" which dictionaries are designed for.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static bool ContainsValue(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string value)
 {
    return dictionary.Keys.Any(k => dictionary[k].Contains(value));            
 }
```

But you should never use a dictionary this way. You should only use it if you want lookup by key. But in this case you are searching a value.

Comment: This is another thing. Thank you! Yes, I know that I should only use dictionaries when I want to lookup by key, but I am testing some problems.

Comment: This finds the keys then does a lookup on each keys - it's simpler to use the `Values` property given that we only care about the values.